# Утечка памяти при создании двумерного массива

Tags: c++

Я в бесконечном цикле создаю массив векторов, которые заполняю значениями (значения типа double), в конце прохода цикла я освобождаю память под новые вектора.
Проблема в том, что после каждой итерации главного цикла while программа ест все больше и больше памяти: после первой - 39,7 мб, после второй - 46,9, третья - 50,7, четверная 54,4 ....
Не могу понять, в чем дело.

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 100000000

int main() {

  double** vector;
  double a = 0;
  while (1 == 1) {

    vector = new double* [SIZE];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      vector[i] = new double[10];      
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {      
    if (j %2 == 0) {
      vector[i][j] = a++;
    } else {
      vector[i][j] = a--;
    }
      }
    }   

    //Освободжаем память
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

      delete [] vector[i];

    }
    delete [] vector;

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103128/discussion-on-question-by-zurn------).